# Ruby on Rails object serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `items` object which is a hash and I want to store it in database table.

Migration:

```
t.string :items
```

Writing:

```
items: items.to_json
```

Reading:

```
@order.items  # returns a string, not a hash as needed.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: _Everything_ is an object in Ruby! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your model the [`serialize`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize)  declaration:

```ruby
class Xyzzy < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :items
end
```

Optionally you may specify a class:

```
serialize :items, Hash
```

so an exception will be thrown if the 'items' object happens to be of some other class.

Also, the column in the database should be declared as `:text`, because the default length of the `:string` column is mere 255 characters, and it may be too short for a serialized object.